# Sort a list of queryset objects from different models by the date_created attribute of object

Tags: django, sorting, django-queryset

I have different models all of which have a 'DateTimeField' named 'date_created'. I need to select all objects from all models, sort them by this field 'date_created' and return as a list.

I have tried the following:

models.py

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()


class SecondModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py

```
def browse(request):
    object_list = []
    for model in get_models(get_app('myapp')):
        object_list.append(model.objects.order_by('-date_created').all())
    object_list = sorted(object_list, key=attrgetter('date_created'))
    context = {'data': object_list}
    return render(request, 'myapp/browse.html', context)
```

I get the error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'date_created'.

These models have other fields irrelevant to this question. I can use a common base class for getting all objects together(I suppose) but I'm using an abstract base class for some reason. I suspect 'joins' could be used but I've no idea how to do that.

So, how can I sort this object_list (which is a list of objects from different models) by date_created attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer with some more research.

The problem is in this line:

```
object_list.append(model.objects.order_by('-date_created').all())
```

While I am using "append", it is treated as a normal list rather than a list of queryset objects { I'm a bit unsure about this, basically this line gives me a list of lists where I need just a list of all the queryset objects. } To correct this [chain()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from itertools can be used by importing chain and replacing above line as shown below:

```
from itertools import chain
...
...
object_list = chain(object_list, (model.objects.order_by('-date_created').all()))
...
```

Rest everything is fine. Also, as its pointed out in question, [multi table inheritence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) could be used which can get all results sorted in a single query by using `order_by`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace this code

```
object_list.append(model.objects.order_by('-date_created').all())
```

with this code :

```
object_list.append(model.objects.all().order_by('-date_created'))
```

And I think you don't need to use this code

```
object_list = sorted(object_list, key=attrgetter('date_created'))
```

Because you've sorted already using "order by"

Comment: Actually, what you are telling would get me sorted lists from different models but I need to sort the final list i.e. combination of all individual sorted model objects list.